# Converting double[] to Double in java

Tags: java, casting, double, type-conversion

I'm new to Java and was wondering was there a way to create a Double object using a double[] array to create it so that the object is populated with the data that's in the array instead of creating it with a single double. I've seen answers of converting from a Double object to a double value but I can't seem to find anything for what i'm stuck on. I'm a bit clueless with this at the moment and would be grateful if anyone could help me out, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Double d = array[0];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cast `double[]` to an `Double`, because of the obvious reason that they are just not **COMPATIBLE**.

If you are storing the `double` values in `double[]` and want to convert individual `double` to `Double`, you need not to `typecast` explicitly. `Autoboxing` works by default.

```
double[] val = {1.01, 3.09};

for(Double d  : val){
// Make use of Double d here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you're reply. I was not sure if this was possible but thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Welcome, Glad that it helped. But please make sure that first search before you ask a question.